# Can anyone help me to find the last 2 digits of this operation.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, power-series

Find the last 2 digits of

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Well, $1993^2\equiv 93^2\equiv 49\pmod{100}$ and so
$1993^4\equiv49^2\equiv1\pmod{100}$. So $1993^x$ modulo $100$
only depends on what $x$ is modulo $4$. What is $x$ here modulo $4$?

Comment: I couldn't follow your answer.can you please elaborate.thanks.

Comment: How does it depend on modulo 4?

Comment: @navinstudent The last 2 digits of $M$ only depend what $M$ is modulo 100.  Now $M=1993^x$ where $x$ is some other ridiculous number. But $x=4y+k$ where $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. Then $M=(1993^4)^y1993^k\equiv 93^k\pmod{100}$. So one only needs to find $k$.

Comment: Now I get you.this implies that once $9999^{10000}$ is encountered its unit digit is 1 and so the value of $k$ is $0$.and hence last two digit is $01$.

Comment: I don't really know how to find $x$ . But what if $x$=10$k$ +4 because 1994=199x10+4

Comment: @NovemberftBlue $x$ is the number $1994^{1995^\cdots}$. You only need to work out what it is modulo $4$.

Comment: Ohh ! So 1994=4$m$+2 where $m$ is 498 And it would be 1993^(4m+2)= (-7)^(4m+2) (mod100). Last two digits of (-7)^4m is 01 and the last 2 digits of (-7)^2 is 49. So 01 x 49 = 49. So the last 2 digits of it is 49? Is that right ?